# SQL phpmyadmin query return most recently date

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

i have a table in my phpmyadmin database with this colomn and data:

```
id    sensor    temp    hum    date

--------------------------------------

1     sensor1   15      20     20/12/2016
2     sensor1   18      0      2/10/2015
3     sensor2   22      10     20/12/2016
4     sensor2   30      22     2/10/2015
5     sensor3   25      15     20/12/2016
```

I want a query that return data like:

```
id    sensor    temp    hum    date

--------------------------------------

1     sensor1   15      20     20/12/2016
3     sensor2   22      10     20/12/2016
5     sensor3   25      15     20/12/2016
```

So i want for each sensor, the most recent date and information.
How can i do this with a query?
Thanks all for help.

**EDIT**

My date are store in this format:

```
Thu Sep 29 2016 11:42:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

**EDIT2**

I have notated that on my db is activated the **only_full_group_by**

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select `id`,`sensor`,`temp`,`hum`, max(`date`)
from table
GROUP BY  `sensor`;
```

Comment: I have try your query without 'id' because it isn't important for my aim, it return me an error like: #1055 - Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'WiFiNetwork.WiFiTH.temp' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: try add temp and hum to group by clause  as well

Comment: it dont return any error, but it return me all the table